# Неявные операторы преобразования типов C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++98

Что происходит в операторе **T operator * ()** класса ***PointerByCopy***

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Pointer {
    private:
        bool m_owner;

    protected:
        T *m_ptr;

    public:
        Pointer(T *ptr) : 
        m_ptr( ptr ? ptr : new T), m_owner( ptr == nullptr ) {

        }

        ~Pointer() {
            if ( m_owner ) delete m_ptr;    
        }
};

template <class T>
class PointerByReference : public Pointer<T> 
{
    public:
        PointerByReference(T *ptr) : Pointer<T>(ptr) {}

        T& operator * () {
            cout << "PointerByReference *" << endl;
            return *Pointer<T>::m_ptr;
        }
};

template <class T>
class PointerByCopy : public Pointer<T> 
{
    public:
        PointerByCopy(T *ptr) : Pointer<T>(ptr) {}

        T operator * () {
            cout << "PointerByCopy *" << endl;
            return *Pointer<T>::m_ptr;
        }
};

template <class T>
class Pointer3 : public Pointer<T> 
{
    public:
        Pointer3(T *ptr) : Pointer<T>(ptr) {}

        operator T * () {
            cout << "Pointer3 *" << endl;
            return Pointer<T>::m_ptr;
        }
};

class Dummy {
    public:
        Dummy()  {
            cout << "Dummy() " << endl; 
        }

        explicit Dummy(Dummy &d) {
            cout << "Dummy(Dummy &d) " << endl; 
        }

        explicit Dummy(const Dummy &d) {
            cout << "Dummy(const Dummy &d) " << endl;   
        }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Dummy d;
    PointerByReference<Dummy> p1(&d);
    PointerByCopy<Dummy> p2(&d);
    Pointer3<Dummy> p3(&d);

    *p1;
    *p2;
    *p3;

    return 0;
}
```

Если убрать ключевое слово ***explicit*** которое является модификатором конструктора класса ***Dummy***, то код скомпилируется.

Компилятор часто дописывает за программиста "хвосты".

## Хочется узнать:

1. что компилятор дописывает в операторе класса ***PointerByCopy*** если убрать ***explicit*** в классе ***Dummy***
2. стоит ли такой конструкцией пользоваться (если да, в каких случаях)
3. стоит ли пользоваться вот такой конструкцией из класса ***Pointer3***:

   ```
   operator T * () {
       cout << "Pointer3 *" << endl;
       return Pointer<T>::m_ptr;
   }
   ```

Comment: Зачем поставлен тэг `[c++98]` если в коде используется `nullptr`?

Comment: Это не столь важно в этом примере. Речь об операторе и explicit.
C++98 added the explicit keyword as a modifier on constructors to prevent single-argument constructors from being used as implicit type conversion operators. However, this does nothing for actual conversion operators.

Answer (score 1):

Оператор `T operator * ()` в классе `PointerByCopy` возвращает *копию* указуемого объекта (в вашем примере - типа `Dummy`). Формирование копии объекта в контексте `return` выполняется в соответствии с семантикой *инициализации копированием*. В контексте инициализации копированием конструкторы, объявленные как `explicit`, не рассматриваются. (В этом и заключается назначение ключевого слова `explicit`). Поэтому ваш код и не компилируется.

Ситуацию с самим оператором `T operator * ()` можно условно "спасти" в рамках C++17, добавив явное копирование в `return`

```
    return T(*Pointer<T>::m_ptr);
```

но в более ранних версиях стандарта языка все равно будет требоваться доступность неявного копирования и так выкрутиться не получится.

Также, как только вы перестанете игнорировать получаемые значения в вызывающем коде, проблема недоступности неявного копирования может встать снова.

---

Что касается ваших вопросов:

1. Ничего никуда не дописывается. См. выше.
2. Какой именно "конструкцией"? Что именно вы пытались реализовать своими классами `Pointer...`?

   При этом вы фактически зачем-то попытались запретить неявное копирование для класса `Dummy`. Зачем?
3. Какой именно "конструкцией"? Что именно вы пытались реализовать своим классом `Pointer3`?

Comment: Я разбираюсь с перегрузкой оператора разыменование указателя.
Компилятор всё же что-то своё пишет взамен return *Pointer<T>::m_ptr;

это как вместо 

MyClass *ptr = new MyClass(...);

будет записано:

MyClass *ptr = new( sizeof(MyClass) );
ptr::MyClass(...);

Comment: @Георгий: То, что "пишет компилятор", диктуется правилами языка. И если ваш код не соответствует правилам языка, то и писать нечего.

Comment: Как это конструкция в операторе разворачивается если убрать explicit?

Comment: Я программирую 5 лет на С++ и мне уже важно знать что там происходит.

Comment: Она "разворачивается" в создание временного объекта - возвращаемого значения функции, при помощи инициализации копированием: `T return_value = *Pointer<T>::m_ptr`.

Comment: А до с++17 если есть explicit конструктор копирования, то ` return T(*Pointer<T>::m_ptr);` - некорректный код? Я правильно понял ? И это как раз из-за инициализации копированием, то есть получится `T return_value = T(*Pointer<T>::m_ptr);` ?

Comment: @vegorov: Да, именно так. Так как RVO тут невозможно, в таком `return` всегда будет хоть одно копирование. В С++17 у нас есть возможность фактически сделать это копирование *явным* и тем самым обойти `explicit`. После нашего явного копирования С++17 уже не будет навешивать сверху еще и свое неявное. А вот до С++17, как ни верти, неявное копирование оставалось.

Comment: @AnT Спасибо. А RVO невозможно потому-что речь идёт о копировании члена класса ? Или потому-что это шаблоны ? Или потому-что есть explicit конструктор копирования? (я просто не знал как этот механизм называется, знал только что компилятор иногда оптимизирует возвращаемое значение без создания лишних локальных объектов, и в том что я нагуглил как пример приводится std::string, он тоже пользовательский тип, шаблон, и для него получается работает RVO) И ещё - получается, что до c++17, если в классе есть explicit конструктор копирования, то копию объекта данного класса нельзя вернуть из метода?

Comment: @vegorov: Ну вся идея RVO в том, что в `return` мы возвращаем *локальный* или *временный* объект и пытаемся исключить создание этого локального или временного объекта как будто его никогда и не было. Здесь же мы работаем с посторонним нелокальным объектом `*mptr`. RVO тут бессильно. Сделать вид, что объекта `*mptr` "никогда не было" мы никак не можем.

Comment: Что касается возврата из функции при `explicit` конструкторе копирования - то да, если я ничего не упускаю, до С++17 это становилось невозможным.